# Pip3 gives "No matching distribution found for ..." error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-module

I have a reqs.txt file, containing many python requirements I need to install on a second computer. The file looks like this:

```
alabaster==0.7.9
anaconda-client==1.6.0
anaconda-navigator==1.4.3
astroid==1.4.9
astropy==1.3
Babel==2.3.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.10.1
...
```

I am using

```
 pip3 install -r reqs.txt --requirement=reqs.txt
```

and I get

```
me@pc:~$ pip3 install -r reqs.txt --requirement=reqs.txt
Collecting alabaster==0.7.9 (from -r reqs.txt (line 1))
Using cached alabaster-0.7.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.0 (from -r reqs.txt (line 2))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.0 (from -r reqs.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.0 (from -r reqs.txt (line 2))
```

for every single package in that reqs.txt file. Any ideas?

EDIT: The reqs.txt file was created with `pip freeze`. Even if I remove the version numbers, they still won't install. If I , however, do a

```
pip3 install alabaster
```

it will install with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The alabaster has no problem in it's installation, however `anaconda-client` isn't available in 1.6.0 using `pip3` probably in your original environment you have a standalone installation of Anaconda so it's version is superior. Thus making the `pip3 install -r reqs.txt` not work, to work you could downgrade the version to one available in pip or install the [conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda) environment on the second computer before running your command.